# Fazer multiplicação de dois números e monstrar resultado (JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT + PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu tenho 3 campos no meu formulário
CAMPO 1: que já tem um valor que puxei no meu banco de dados que é o preço o produto
Campo 2: a onde eu vou inserir um número inteiro indicando a quantidade do produto que quero adicionar
Campo 3: o total da multiplicação que sera Campo 1(preço do produto) X campo 2 (quantidade de produto)

Só que fazendo isso, o retorno do valor no meu código está me dando "NaN" e não porque?Preciso de ajuda para entender o que fiz de errado. Já passei 3 horas isso e não consigo entender.**DESCONSIDERAR O CAMPO ESCRITO "VALOR VENDA EM R$" na IMAGEM**

### IMAGEM DE EXEMPLO

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está meu condigo HTML:

```
                 <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 calculate">
                           <label>Valor Tabelado</label>
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_tabela" id="valor_tabela" value="R$<?=$put['valor_tabela']?>" readonly>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3 calculate">
                          <label>Quantidade</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty"   name="quantidade" value="0">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 calculate">
                          <label>Sub Total</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="result" name="sub_total"   readonly>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>

    $(".calculate").click(function () {
    var value = '<?=$put['valor_tabela']?>';
    var primaryincome = $("#qty").val();
    var otherincome = $("#valor_tabela").val(value);
    var totalincome = parseInt(primaryincome) + parseFloat(otherincome);
    alert(totalincome);
    $("#result").val(totalincome);
})
    </script>
```

Comment: Parece que você não fechou a tag label, isso pode estar dando erro no seu html então quando você vai pegar o input com id valor_tabela, ela retorna undefined. E numero + undefined retorna NaN

Comment: acabei de testar e mesmo assim continua mostrando o "NaN"

Comment: Como está fazendo direto com Jquery não há necessidade de receber esses valores de tantas formas diferentes, padronize um pouco:
var value = $("#valor_tabela").val();
Faça dessa forma para todos teste e veja se irá calcular, em caso de erro teste com valores estáticos dentro da função, particione seu problema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o retorno da variável `otherincome` é um objeto e está tentando realizar uma soma com um objeto, você deve setar um valor ao `input[id="valor_tabela"]` e em seguida recuperar seu valor.
Por exemplo:

```
var otherincome = $("#valor_tabela").val(value).val()
```

É atribuído um valor ao `input` e em seguida recuperado esse valor.

#### Ficando algo desse tipo:

```js
$("#calcular").click(function () {
    var value = 1467.73;
    var primaryincome = $("#qty").val();
    var otherincome = $("#valor_tabela").val(value).val();
    // Alterado o sinal de '+', para  '*'
    var totalincome = parseInt(primaryincome) * parseFloat(otherincome);
    alert(totalincome);
    $("#result").val(totalincome);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 calculate">
            <label>Valor Tabelado</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_tabela" id="valor_tabela" value="1467.73" readonly>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 calculate">
            <label>Quantidade</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty"   name="quantidade" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 calculate">
            <label>Sub Total</labe>
            <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="result" name="sub_total"   readonly>
        </div>
        <button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a sua resposta não foi muito clara para mim infelizmente, sabendo que não sou brasileiro tbm então ficou meio confuso

Comment: adicionado um exemplo prático

Comment: agradeço, você foi muito mais prático. a sua resposta está certa, mas não sei o pq aqui continua mostrando "NaN" mesmo copiando sua resposta e colando aqui.

Comment: Me envie seu código pelo chat que lhe ajudo!

Comment: nem sabia que tinha chat aqui, mas veja se consegue entrar nesse link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103677/help-with-jquery